# Set Last Updated on each SaveChanges in Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using SQLite with EntityFramework. 
All my entities inherit from `BaseEntity`, that has property:

```
 DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
```

is it possible to automatically set `LastUpdated` to `DateTime.Now` everytime entity is updated in database? I was thinking either about overriding `SaveChanges()` method or doing something (not sure what) in getter or setter of the property.

Comment: I would override SaveChanges or implement SetAdded/SetModified to set this property, depending on what time you would want to see. Of course you could override getter or setter, but since noone can be sure when EF calls the getters and setters of their DbSet entries, I would advise against it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it by overriding `SaveChanges` method:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    IEnumerable<DbEntityEntry<BaseEntity>> entries = ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>()
            .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified);

    foreach (DbEntityEntry<BaseEntity> entry in entries)
    {
        entry.Entity.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```